# The Unicode look of disapproval no longer displays correctly in 16.04 - how do I fix this?

Tags: 16.04, fonts, unicode

The [Unicode look of disapproval](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/_-look-of-disapproval) no longer displays correctly within Chrome and Firefox in Ubuntu 16.04:

[image]

As you can see, the Unicode replacement character is shown instead of the correct symbol.
This was working fine in 15.04 - what do I need to do to get this fixed?

Comment: I read that as "The unicorn look of disapproval" the first time...

Comment: Please note that even when you install the additional font per the accepted answer, your audience viewers may not have it installed by default, so relying on it as a universal expression is a bit iffy.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The Unicode Look of Disapproval (U0CA0) uses the letter ttha from the Kannada language.

You can `sudo apt install fonts-lohit-knda` to provide the correct font.

You can then insert the character with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>, then `0CA0`

ಠ_ಠ

Comment: ಠ_____________ಠ

Comment: Any idea why this font is suddenly excluded by default? It worked on all previous releases without installing additional fonts... It was even gone on my machine that upgraded from 15.10 to 16.04.

Comment: @ByteCommander I couldn't find a definitive answer. Traditionally lohit fonts are installed in various distros. My *guess* is that removing it from the default is part of a general streamlining related to UT.

Comment: ✌___ ಠ   ͜    ಠ  ___✌