# Which font is needed to display a specific Unicode character?

Tags: fonts, unicode

Sometimes (e.g. in my Firefox browser) I see those Unicode fallback characters like the one below for the Unicode character U+0880 (just an example) instead of the real character.

[image: Unicode fallback character U+0880]

Another example would be the character U+0CA0 which is used to represent the eyes in the famous "Unicode look of disapproval" (ಠ_ಠ ) emoticon, which needs the `fonts-lohit-knda` package installed to display correctly: 
[The Unicode look of disapproval no longer displays correctly in 16.04 - how do I fix this?](https://askubuntu.com/q/765633/367990)

I know this is because I miss a font containing this character, but how can I determine which font package I need to install to display a specific Unicode character correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The website you have visited chose a font for that text to be rendered in, or accepted your browser's defaults. Your browser displays it in the selected font. It doesn't pick and choose to find fonts that have that character listed.

You need to choose a font that has Kannada symbols and display your text in that. This might require instructing your browser not to honor websites' font choices.

Unfortunately, I'm not sure what fonts are available that cover Kannada.